# PowerShell Form: Sometimes starts in the background

Tags: winforms, powershell

I wrote a little GUI for a script that I use on daily basis. Sometimes the window starts in the background behind all other windows I have opened. In this case there will even be no icon in the task bar. This phenomenon looks like the script is not started. When I minimize all other windows I can see the script GUI and after clicking into it the icon on the task bar appears.

Here is how I defined the PowerShell form:

```
[void] [system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("system.windows.forms")
[void] [system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("system.drawing")

$window = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$window.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$window.AutoSize = $False
$window.MinimizeBox = $False
$window.MaximizeBox = $False
$window.FormBorderStyle = "FixedToolWindow"

[...]

$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Does anyone know what I can do to ensure that the GUI is always started on top?

Comment: I don't know Powershell pretty well but I know C# and WinForms and I think it's pretty similar. Try using `WindowState` property. Like `$window.WindowState = "Normal"`. As I said I'm not familiar with Powershell. Thats also the reason why this is a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately, the property WindowState doesnt fix the problem. The windows is still sometimes appearing in the background ...

Comment: Hmm okay, I'm sorry but I don't know Powershell that good so I cannot help you further :/ I hope someone who knows the answer comes here and will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, very kind from you. Aprreciate!

Comment: You could try setting the TopMost property to $True: `TopMost=$True`. This should ensure that it stays at the top, but then it will always be at the top so you will need some code to set it to $False after it has loaded the form or on some other event.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your apporach. Still this does not solve the problem. The GUI is still opening in the back sometimes ...

Comment: It definitely could be a system/graphics bug. Does this happen on any other computer ?

Comment: Nope, on different computers ... It seems to be very strange?